Combinatorics - variation of the stars and bars problem
How do you find the number of ways to choose 6 distinct natural numbers from first 120 natural numbers such that any two chosen numbers differ by atleast 8?
I understand that this can be interpreted as a stars and bars problem but I am unsure of how to proceed and apply it here.

Hint:  consider the gaps between your selections (including start and end gaps).  The start and end gaps can be any non-negative integer, but the internal ones have to be at least $8$.

$\underline{\mathtt{A\; Variant\; Method}}$

Make $5$ blocks of $1$ chosen and $7$ unchosen, and one short block of chosen $\boxed{\bullet\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ}\; and \; \boxed{\bullet}$
There are now $85\;$ entities $\;$ including $79$ singles
Place the blocks in $\binom{85}6$ ways, with short block last. The position of bullets in the line  gives the chosen numbers

